# I want to capture serial printer information so that I can manipulate the data

Tags: printing, serial-port, capture

I need to be able to adjust the bitrate, start, stop, and parity. I would like to use a Single Board Computer or an old Android Phone that is rooted and running a different version of Linux. The data is important, so having a screen to be sure that I am recording data would be nice. I need the data saved in a way that I can manipulate it and import it into a spreadsheet. I am new to Linux, I have a laptop running it and I am still learning. I am currently using windows and hyperterminal to capture the data. I am looking for a more compact solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screen`

> screen /dev/ttyUSB0 57600

Check the manpage for the other parameters you want to be able to adjust.